# Oracle SDO_JOIN, how long does it takes?

Tags: oracle, join, spatial, geography, oracle-spatial

I wanna use the SDO_JOIN-Operator to selfJoin a table. 
The table has this Structure:
ID         VARCHAR2(20)
SHAPE      SDO_GEOMETRY()

The table has 25778 rows.

The following SDO_JOIN-Statement needs 90 seconds:

```
SELECT w.id as id1, w2.id as id2
FROM TABLE(SDO_JOIN('nodesWays', 'SHAPE', 'nodesWays', 'SHAPE', 'mask=ANYINTERACT')) c,
nodesWays w, nodesWays w2
WHERE c.rowid1 = w.rowid AND c.rowid2 = w2.rowid;
```

Is 90 Seconds a normal time or is it too high. I don't have an idea what is a good time for execution.

Bye, Andre

Answer (score 0):

SDO_JOIN is designed to match many spatial objects with many others: it is a "batch" kind of operation, so it will take time, and the more objects you need to match the longer it will obviously take. How long it takes also obviously depends on the kind of hardware you run it on. CPU capacity is key.

About your query, start by removing the SDO_GEOM.RELATE call. It is unnecessary since it is already done by the main SDO_JOIN query. Also I see no reason for using those hints. So try this:

```
SELECT w.id as id1, w2.id as id2
FROM TABLE(SDO_JOIN('nodesWays', 'SHAPE', 'nodesWays', 'SHAPE', 'mask=ANYINTERACT')) c,
nodesWays w, nodesWays w2
WHERE c.rowid1 = w.rowid 
AND c.rowid2 = w2.rowid
and c.rowid1 < c.rowid2;
```

How long does this take ?

Is 90 seconds a good time ? Is 50 seconds a good time ? How long is a piece of string ?

The real questions is: is 90 or 50 seconds a good time for your application workflow ? Does it meet your business requirements ? If so you are all set. If you want the results faster, try running it on a system with more CPU power, i.e. faster processors.

Note that SDO_JOIN does not currently exploit the parallelism provided by multi-core/multi-cpu servers. You can still use parallelism, but that needs rewriting the query and makes the syntax more complicated. Then again ask yourself the question: is it worth the effort to get the response faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the explain plan you posted I suspect you'll probably struggle to get it to run any faster unless you put run on better hardware with faster CPU.  Note that sdo_join is far faster in 12c with SPATIAL_VECTOR_ACCELERATION=TRUE, so if possible try to run on that release... even if only to benchmark how fast it can be.

Comment: I just want to know if I implemented it correct. Or if there are possibilities for optimization.

Comment: I will try your suggestion with the SPATIAL_VECTOR_ACCELERATION=TRUE.